# Could GA from a third party iframe affect the host site GA data?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, cross-domain, google-analytics-api

The problem that i have with google analytics that it has been eating my head for a while now it is the follow:
since I added a third party iframe into the website the analytics referrals are going nuts, first they were adding fake visits, but this got solved with adding filters. but the referrals still not registing which page refers to the site like it did before...

the google analytics code it is just standar one:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'xxxxxxx.xxx']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

and there is another push events for tracking clicks or functions calls, and the analytics inside the iframe is this one:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-3']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'b.xxxxxxxxxx.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['external._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']); //this is my domain ga number
_gaq.push(['external._trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

and they also have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 979036530;
var google_conversion_language = "da";
var google_conversion_format = "2";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "-BBnCIbQiwUQ8tLr0gM";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
```

any idea what could be creating this mix on the google analytics referrals? any help it is really appreciated thanks

***UPDATE:***
Before i forget i did add filters like this one: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it should work fine if everything is set-up correctly. Although, it is particular.

### Questions

- Which referrals are going crazy? Host site or 3rd party site?
- How are referrals expected to be tracked? Referral url or UTM data?
- Are you passing along your referral data some how?
- Are you crossing between http and https anywhere?

### Ideas/Solutions

You should try and have utm variables in your urls whenever possible. Referral urls are flakey and don't work between new windows or http/https changes. So your link between your window and iframe is definitely NOT passing referral data by default.

When switching pages between domains normally you need to use [_link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._link), but for iframes you need to use [_getLinkerUrl](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._getLinkerUrl). The only thing _setAllowLinker lets you do is use the _link method and it has no other magic really that helps you.

In your case you need to set the iframe to something like about:blank at first, then:

```
_gaq.push(function() {
  var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
  var iframe = document.getElementById('third-party-iframe');
  iframe.src = pageTracker._getLinkerUrl('http://3rdparty-iframe');
});
```

Which will change the iframe's location as soon as google analytics loads. This sucks a little bit. You may want to have a check of some sort, if gaq fails to load after some time load the iframe anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

*the referral that it is going crazy it is the host one, we dont know anything about how the 3rd party analytics.
*data it is expected as full referral url
*no im not passing my referral data.
*no the main site as the 3rd party iframe are http protocols

thanks for the ideas/solution i will implement them to see if there is some changes. :)